# Enable mouse back button action inside citrix workspace window

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, virtualbox

I have a MacBook Pro(macOS 10.15.3) and am logged into a Windows 10 system through Citrix Viewer. I have a Logitech MX Master 3 connected to MacBook through bluetooth. The back navigation button works fine in chrome when I am on my macOS but it doesn't work in the Windows desktop through Citrix. Is there any setting which I can enable to make this work?
Sorry for tagging virtualbox, citrix tag wasn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made this working using steps from parallel's website (https://kb.parallels.com/114322)

Basically you assign the correct Hotkey combination as a "Keystroke Assignment" within the Logi Options app.

I would improve the KB though - they assign the key for "All Applications" - effectively breaking backward/forward button for native/other apps. So to avoid that I set these keystrokes for the "Citrix Viewer" App specifically